# How to find the integral of $\tan x - \sec x\tan x$?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int(\tan x - \sec x\tan x)dx$$

I rewrote the integral like this:

$$\int\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}- \sec x\tan x\right)dx$$

and using $u$-substitution for the first term I got a final answer of:

$$-\ln|\cos x| - \sec x + c$$

Where was my mistake?

Comment: Why do you think you made a mistake? Have you seen another result, likely equal (to within an additive integration constant) by a trigonometric identity?

Comment: @J.G. The answer sheet's solution was $ln|secx|-secx + c$.

Comment: Then your answer sheet is wrong:$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln|\sec x|=\frac{\sec x\tan x}{\sec x}=\tan x.$$

Comment: What's the difference between $\ln|\sec x|$ and $-\ln|\cos x|$?

Comment: @J.G. So there can be more than one antiderivative to tanx? Wouldn't this create different answers when trying to evaluate definite integrals?

Comment: @RudyGoburt All we're using is $\sec x=\tfrac{1}{\cos x}\implies\ln|\sec x|=-\ln|\cos x|$.

Comment: @J.G. I put in a value x for both answers and they had the same answer. I understand now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made no mistake.

Going to explain a bit to be clearer.

The first part is correct for
$$\int \tan(x)\ \text{d}x = -\ln|\cos(x)| + c_1$$
and this is easy (you just see the tangent as sine/cosine recognising it has the form $f'(x)/f(x)$ (with a minus sign) which is nothing but a logarithmic derivative.

About the second term:

$$\int \sec(x)\tan(x)\ \text{d}x = \sec(x) + c_2$$

Indeed by the definition: $\sec(x) = \dfrac{1}{\cos(x)}$

We have

$$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \sec(x) = \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)} \equiv \dfrac{1}{\cos(x)}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \sec(x)\tan(x)$$

And of course the constant vanished in the derivative.

You made no mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan x-\sec x\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\frac1{\cos x}\frac{\sin}{\cos x}$$
If we first try and do the integral of $\tan x$:
$$I_1=\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}dx$$
$u=\cos x\Rightarrow dx=-\frac{du}{\sin x}$ and so:
$$I_1=-\int\frac1udu=-\ln|u|+C_1=-\ln|\cos x|+C_1=\ln|\sec x|+C_1$$
and now for $\sec x\tan x$:
$$I_2=\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}dx$$
$$=-\int\frac1{u^2}du=\frac1u+C_2=\frac1{\cos x}+C_2=\sec x+C_2$$
and so:
$$\int\tan x-\sec x\tan xdx=\ln|\sec x|-\sec x+C_3$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\log|\sec(x)|=-\log|\cos(x)|
$$
If we remove the absolute value signs, then this is obvious:
\begin{align}
\log\left(\cos(x)^{-1}\right)=-\log(\cos(x)) \, .
\end{align}
This still holds for $\log|\sec(x)|$ and $-\log|\cos(x)|$. This can be verified by noting that $\log|\sec(x)|$ is equal to $\log\left(\sec(x)\right)$ or $\log\left(-\sec(x)\right)$, and whenever $\sec$ is positive, so is $\cos$.